# How to use delegated events?

Tags: javascript, delegates, jquery

I'm using an event to replace "src" attributes in some layers (`<div class="total-title" src="anURL">`):

```
$('.playOnAP').on('click',function() {
    $('#mp3-list ul li',this).each( function( index, element ) {
    $('.total-title').eq(index).attr('src', $(this).text() );
});
```

and it works the first time, but not after an Ajax request, when the `$('.playOnAP')` elements are replaced. I'm guessing I should use [Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), but don't make myself clear.

I've tried the next:

```
$('.playOnAP').on('click','#mp3-list ul li',function() {
$('.playOnAP #mp3-list ul li').on('click',function() {
$('.playOnAP #mp3-list ul li').on('click','#mp3-list ul li',function() {
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Are you replacing the element `.playOnAp` itself or just its contents?

Comment: @PSL - The whole elements

Comment: then do `$('parentOfplayOnAPOrdocument').on('click','.playOnAP #mp3-list ul li',function() {` Basically you want to bind the event to the container element that exists in DOM as long as you need the event.

Comment: `->` http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ `<-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.playOnAP',function() {
```

When using event delegation, you must bind the event to an element that was originally in the DOM. If something has been dynamically replaced, you cannot bind to that.

As Anup insightfully mentioned, it is not strictly necessary to bind the click event to `document` -- any parent element will do, as long as it was originally in the DOM.

For example, if `.playOnAP` is the topmost container element that is being replaced:

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <div class="playOnAP">
        //some stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

You could use:

```
$('#someDiv').on('click', '.playOnAP', function() { //do your stuff });
```

As a default, though, you can pretty much always use `$(document).on()` (even if just as a quick check to make sure everything works before narrowing down to the most appropriate element).

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please explain the problem and your solution.

Comment: @gibberish: Instead of $(document), try adding event on its closest parent... $("its-closest-parent").on("click" ".playOnAP..", function() {..})

Comment: Yes, it works after the edit. Thanks. So fast :) Too soon to mark as answered xD

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the delegate on a parent of .playOnAp if you are replacing .playOnAp.  The event handlers only attach to DOM elements that exist when you add the event handler.