# Ajax event doesn't work after replacing the event's element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this snippet code inside a JQuery plugin:

```
function addToPlayList() {
    $('.playOnAP').on('click',function() {
    console.log('play!!');
    if( supports_mp3_audio() ) {
        console.log('soporta mp3');
        $('#mp3-list ul li',this).each( function( index, element ) {

            $('.total-title').eq(index).attr('src', $(this).text() );
            });     
    } else if ( supports_ogg_audio() ) {

        console.log('soporta ogg');
        $('#ogg-list ul li',this).each( function( index, element ) {

            $('.total-title').eq(index).attr('src', $(this).text() );
            });     
    }
    console.log($('.total-title').first().attr('src'));
    songPlay($('.total-title').first().attr('src'));
    htmlSound.play(); 
    $('.total-play').addClass('total-pause');

    });
}
addToPlayList();
```

It works the first time I load the page. But after an Ajax request, I get new `$('.playOnAP')` elements, and the event is no longer triggered.

All other plugin's functions work right, but the above one. Any idea?

**Edit:**

Finally found out with this answer: [How to use delegated events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891186/how-to-use-delegated-events/#answer-20891232)

Comment: Why you have the onClick event within a function call?

Comment: this is not a WordPress issue, this is purely javascript. read the section titled [**Direct and delegated events** in Jquery docs for `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an AJAX function in the code you posted.  However, if you do replace the `.playOnAP` once the AJAX function is executed, I would recommend using [delegated events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).  You do this by binding the function to the nearest **static** element.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="item">New Item ' + (new Date().getTime()) + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: You can see here how I solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891186/how-to-use-delegated-events/#answer-20891232

Comment: Okay, sorry.  I just saw this question migrated and wanted to post an answer.